# Unwanted spaces between characters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, letterspacing

When typesetting `$INDEX^{LOYALTY}$` in math mode, I realize that it creates a space in between Character Y and A. I just wonder if there is any way to remove this unwanted gap.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left = 2.5 cm, right=2.5 cm, top = 2.5 cm, bottom = 2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$INDEX^{LOYALTY}$
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I confirm this on my just updated TeXLive 2018 distribution. Which TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Hi Marmot, I'm using MikTex.

Comment: Hmmh, I thought the question was really on the fact that the space after the Y *in* *math* *mode* is so large.

Comment: @marmot, I'm pretty curious about that as well.

Comment: all the spaces are large because the font is designed to make sure adjacent letters do not look like a word bur rather a product of single letter variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to interpret the letters in `INDEX` and `LOYALTY` as words, not individual symbols, you can use `\mathrm{}` (Roman font in math mode.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\( \mathrm{INDEX}^\mathrm{LOYALTY} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: INDEX^LOYALTY]

This also works with `unicode-math`, which will set the words in your text font and has a separate `\symup{}` command for upright letters that are individual symbols, not words.

One way to get text-mode italic letters is with `\mathit{}` from `unicode-math` or `amsfonts`.  This is what I recommend.  You can also wrap arbitrary text-mode formatting inside `\text{}` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \mathit{INDEX}^{\mathit{LOYALTY}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: using \mathit]

Comment: @OrangeEfficiency You’re welcome, but if you take another look, I recommend the one on the bottom.

Comment: Or, consider `\( \textit{INDEX}^{\textit{LOYALTY}} \)`, for improved kerning (esp. between O and Y and between Y and A).

Comment: @Mico The superscripts are too big that way.  `^{\text{\textit{LOYALTY}}}` works if you `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: @Davislor - You're right. In my own code, I was indeed loading the `amsmath` package. (Aside: Unless one's document contains no math material at all, including any subscript or superscript material, I can't think of a good reason for loading the `amsmath` package...)

Comment: @Mico Do you mean, for not loading it? Here, I was trying to keep the examples minimal.

Comment: @Davislor - Oops, my bad! Indeed, I *meant* to write, "I can't think of a good reason for not loading the `amsmath` package." Argh